# Using grpc with latest appengine sdk (golang 1.4.2)

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Using latest appengine SDK which is go version 1.4.2 under the hood:

`go get google.golang.org/grpc` fails due to dependency on http2 which evidently doesn't work with the current appengine sdk release. Seems http2 stuff is only available only from 1.6+:

> from Go 1.6 and later

(ref: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/http2)

calling `go get golang.org/x/net/http2` did not fix the errors

While I originally caught this in working with google cloud storage, seems it's used throughout this library:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grpc

Answer (score 2):

update the http2 package using

```
go get -u golang.org/x/net/http2
```

from the description of go commands (https://golang.org/cmd/go/):

> The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named
>   packages and their dependencies. By default, get uses the network to
>   check out missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to
>   existing packages.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with my local configuration somehow:

Just for the record...

**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ more ~/.bash_profile**

> export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
>   export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
>   export GOPATH=/Users/davidk/Documents/golang
>   export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH

**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ go version**

> go version go1.6 darwin/amd64

**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ /Applications/go_appengine/goapp version**

> go version go1.4.2 (appengine-1.9.33) darwin/amd64

**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ mkdir ./TEMP_GOPATH**
**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ export GOPATH=/Users/davidk/Desktop/TEMP_GOPATH**
**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ go get google.golang.org/grpc**
**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ go get google.golang.org/cloud/storage**

(i.e. everything is fine, but then...)

**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ export GOPATH=/Users/davidk/Documents/golang**
**davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$ go get google.golang.org/grpc**

> # google.golang.org/grpc/transport
>   ../Documents/golang/src/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:678: undefined: http2.MetaHeadersFrame
>   ../Documents/golang/src/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:774: undefined: http2.MetaHeadersFrame
>   ../Documents/golang/src/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_server.go:140: undefined: http2.MetaHeadersFrame
>   ../Documents/golang/src/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_server.go:253: undefined: http2.MetaHeadersFrame
>   ../Documents/golang/src/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http_util.go:279: f.fr.ReadMetaHeaders undefined (type *http2.Framer has no field or method ReadMetaHeaders)
>   davidk-osx:Desktop davidk$